# Polyglot array_extend() function for Javascript and PHP

Tags: javascript, php, array, polyglot

This is a polyglot function I've made out of fun.

The goal is to grab `n` arrays (or Javascript `Object`s) and 'extend' them in order to obtain a single array with all the values.

This function runs both in Javascript and PHP.

Please, try to ignore some *[kludges](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/kludge#English)* on my code.

Here is my 'art':

```
function array_extend() {

    //Detects if we are running in Javascript or PHP
    //In PHP, this will be false because PHP only parses
    //escape sequences in double-quoted strings (except the sequence \')
    $javascript = '\0' == "\0";

    //PHP arrays support 'key=>value' pairs, JS arrays don't.
    $result = $javascript ? new Object() : array();

    $arguments = $javascript? arguments : func_get_args();

    $get_keys = function($elem){
        if('\0' == "\0")//PHP complains if I use the var $javascript
        {
            $object = Object;
            return $object['keys']($elem); //PHP doesn't like the Object.keys syntax
        }
        else
        {
            return array_keys($elem);
        }
    };


    for($j = 0, $length_args = $javascript? $arguments['length']: count($arguments); $j < $length_args; $j++)
    {
        $keys = $get_keys( $arguments[$j] );

        for($i = 0, $length_keys = $javascript? $keys['length']: count($keys); $i < $length_keys; $i++)
        {
            $result[$keys[$i]] = $arguments[$j][$keys[$i]];
        }
    }

    return $result;
}
```

Example of usage:

```
array_extend([1,2,3,4,5],[9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1,0]);
//should return the last elements in the array:

array_extend({'a':1, 'b':2, 'c':3},{test:'nice'});
//Javascript: returns {'a':1, 'b':2, 'c':3, test:'nice'}

array_extend(array('a'=>1, 'b'=>2, 'c'=>3), array('test'=>'nice'));
//PHP: returns array('a'=>1, 'b'=>2, 'c'=>3, 'test'=>'nice')
```

What do you guys think?

What can I improve? Where should I have done something better?

Comment: Wait....so you made a  function that compiles to both PHP *AND* Javascript???

Comment: @jsanc623 Yes, that's exactly it. You can fire up your console, paste it and use it *OR* you can slap it in a PHP file and run this bad boy!

Comment: Wh...why?? What are you trying to build? Please tell me this is just a learning exercise...

Comment: @jsanc623 I was bored and simply made this. No, it isn't an exercise. I really just made this out of fun. I saw a question on stackoverflow to do something similar (it wasn't asking a polyglot) and did this. To be honest, I enjoy making this kind of stuff.

Comment: That's honorable at least

Comment: @jsanc623 Thank you a lot! All the "magic" in this code is based in the fact that `'\0' == "\0"` is `true` in Javascript but `false` in PHP. Both share most of the syntax. And the `$` symbol is available everywhere. PHP requires all variables to start with `$` while Javascript simply allows it. That `$get_keys` function is the 'core' for this to work. Without it, I couldn't do much. What do you think about the code itself?

Comment: Honestly, I wouldn't touch it - I don't see any gains

Comment: @jsanc623 I don't see much that I can improve. I could use better scoping (since this function is 'leaking' into the `window` object). But the `var` keyword isn't allowed outside classes, in PHP. If there was a way to make a single local variable with Javascript in a non-obstructive way that works for both languages, I would use it. But that's it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may want to replace object key access notation with dot notation.

For example, instead of the following.

```
$object['keys']($elem);
```

Write this.

```
Object.keys($elem);
```

This works, because `Object` is interpreted as a constant, dot as concatenation, and `keys($elem)` as function call. Use of undefined constant doesn't warn if the code with it is not executed. Unknown functions don't error if they aren't called.

Comment: For some reason it failed to me. A LOT! That's why I used that weird *kludge*. But it worked now and it's worth noticing. Also, you can add there that I forgot the order of the variables. `$i` should be in the first loop and `$j` should be in the 2nd. If you find a way to make a local variable for Javascript without the keyword `var` (sounds insane, I know), I would thank you a lot!